# Writing applications with Scala actors in practice

Tags: scala, actor

I've now written a few applications using scala actors and I'm interested in how people have approached or dealt with some of the problems I've encountered.

**A plethora of Message classes or !?**

I have an actor which reacts to a user operation and must cause something to happen. Let's say it `react`s to a message `UserRequestsX(id)`. A continuing problem I have is that, because I want to modularize my programs, a single actor on its own is unable to complete the action without involving other actors. For example, suppose I need to use the `id` parameter to retrieve a bunch of values and then these need to be deleted via some other actor. If I were writing a normal Java program, I might do something like:

```
public void reportTrades(Date date) {
    Set<Trade> trades = persistence.lookup(date);
    reportService.report(trades);
}
```

Which is simple enough. However, using actors this becomes a bit of a pain because I want to avoid using  **`!?`**. One actor reacts to the `ReportTrades(date)` message but it must ask a `PersistenceActor` for the trades and then a `ReportActor` to report them. The only way I've found of doing this is to do:

```
react {
    case ReportTrades(date) =>
       persistenceActor ! GetTradesAndReport(date)
}
```

So that in my `PersistenceActor` I have a react block:

```
react {
    case GetTradesAndReport(date) =>
       val ts = trades.get(date) //from persietent store
       reportActor ! ReportTrades(ts)
}
```

But now I have 2 problems:

1. I have to create extra message classes to represent *the same request* (i.e. "report trades"). In fact I have three in this scenario but I may have many more - it becomes a problem keeping track of these
2. What should I call the first and third message `ReportTrades`? It's confusing to call them both `ReportTrades` (or if I do, I must put them in separate packages). Essentially there is no such thing as `overloading` a class by `val` type.

Is there something I'm missing? Can I avoid this? Should I just give up and use **`!?`** Do people use some organizational structure to clarify what is going on?

Comment: Is it safe to access the persistent store directly in "react" ?  I thought you couldn't do blocking operations.  Maybe "receive" is needed for that particular actor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me, your `ReportTrades` message is mixing two different concepts. One is a Request, the order is a Response. They might be named `GetTradesReport(Date)` and `SendTradesReport(List[Trade])`, for example. Or, maybe, `ReportTradesByDate(Date)` and `GenerateTradesReport(List[Trade])`.

Comment: But my point still stands; I have all these classes used for nothing other than passing data around. Yesterday I wrote some code whereby I needed to "decorate" a request with information from 4 separate actors. Even allowing for sensible naming, it is a lot of confusing classes!

Comment: Well, such classes are never used just to convey information. They are used to convey information from one place to another for a purpose. If you name them accordingly, you improve the overall legibility of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Are there some objections to using `reply`? Or passing `trades` around? If not, your code would probably look like

```
react {
  case ReportTrades(date) => persistenceActor ! GetTrades(date)
  case Trades(ts) => // do smth with trades
}
```

and

```
react {
  case GetTrades(date) => reply(Trades(trades.get(date)))
}
```

respectively.

Comment: I guess my point is that I can't just pass a `Trades` object back to my coordinator as *how would it know which original command was being invoked?* For example, I may have several things I need to do: *DeleteTrades*, *ReportTrades*, *LoadTrades* etc. The coordinator is  going to need to get a response like `SomeTradesToReport`, `SomeTradesToDelete` or `SomeTradesToLoad` (assuming I am avoiding `!?`)