# Is this a bug in scala 2.9.0.1 actor library

Tags: scala, scala-2.9

The following code works fine in Scala 2.8 but not in 2.9.0.1
(copy and paste in REPL). This will throw an exception in 2.9.0.1.

```
import scala.actors.Actor
import scala.actors.TIMEOUT

object A2 extends Actor {
  def act = {
    loop {
      react {
        case "hello" => 
          val s = sender 
          reactWithin(2000){
            case i:Int => s ! "hello"
            case TIMEOUT => s ! "TIMEOUT"
          }
        case _ => 
      }
    }
  }
}

object A1 extends Actor {
  def act = {
    loop {
      react {
        case m:String => println (A2 !? (1000, m))
        case _ =>
      }
    }
  }
}

A1.start
A2.start

A1 ! "hi"
A1 ! "hello"
```

If the exception is not thrown immediately, keep doing `A1 ! "hi"` or `A1 ! "hello"` a few times.

Is this a bug in Scala 2.9.0.1, or something wrong with the code?

[EDIT] Forgot to add the actual exception thrown.

```
scala> $line4.$read$$iw$$iw$A1$@6be03fce: caught java.lang.RuntimeException: unhandled timeout
java.lang.RuntimeException: unhandled timeout
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
    at scala.actors.Actor$class.receiveWithin(Actor.scala:606)
    at $line4.$read$$iw$$iw$A1$.receiveWithin(<console>:10)
    at scala.actors.Channel.receiveWithin(Channel.scala:71)
    at scala.actors.ActorCanReply$class.$bang$qmark(ActorCanReply.scala:32)
    at $line3.$read$$iw$$iw$A2$.$bang$qmark(<console>:9)
    at $line4.$read$$iw$$iw$A1$$anonfun$act$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(<console>:15)
    at $line4.$read$$iw$$iw$A1$$anonfun$act$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(<console>:13)
    at scala.actors.ReactorTask.run(ReactorTask.scala:31)
    at scala.actors.Reactor$class.resumeReceiver(Reactor.scala:129)
    at $line4.$read$$iw$$iw$A1$.scala$actors$ReplyReactor$$super$resumeReceiver(<console>:10)
    at scala.actors.ReplyReactor$class.resumeReceiver(ReplyReactor.scala:68)
    at $line4.$read$$iw$$iw$A1$.resumeReceiver(<console>:10)
    at scala.actors.Actor$class.searchMailbox(Actor.scala:500)
    at $line4.$read$$iw$$iw$A1$.searchMailbox(<console>:10)
    at scala.actors.Reactor$$anonfun$startSearch$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(Reactor.scala:117)
    at scala.actors.Reactor$$anonfun$startSearch$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Reactor.scala:114)
    at scala.actors.Reactor$$anonfun$startSearch$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Reactor.scala:114)
    at scala.actors.ReactorTask.run(ReactorTask.scala:33)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$AdaptedRunnable.exec(ForkJoinPool.java:611)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.quietlyExec(ForkJoinTask.java:422)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.mainLoop(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:340)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:325)
```

EDIT2: Standalone program without REPL

```
package scalaapplication5
import scala.actors.Actor._
import scala.actors.Actor
import scala.actors.TIMEOUT


object Main {
  A1.start
  A2.start
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    while (true){
      A1 ! "hi"
      A1 ! "hello"
      Thread.sleep(1000)
    }
  }
}

object A2 extends Actor {
  def act = loop { 
    react {
      case "hello" =>
        val s = sender
        reactWithin(2000){
          case i:Int => s ! "hello"
          case TIMEOUT => s ! "TIMEOUT"
        }
      case _ =>
    }
  }
}

object A1 extends Actor {
  def act = {
    loop {
      react {
        case m:String => println (A2 !? (1000, m))
        case _ =>
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: "Is this a bug in Scala 2.9.0.1, or something wrong with the code?" - I can't tel the difference between Scala and Esperanto, but I know the answer to that question is almost invariably "it's your code" :-)

Comment: Did you try with Scala 2.8, and see that no exception is thrown, but is thrown in 2.9.x

Comment: Has no one else been able to reproduce this behavior? Please try with Scala 2.9.0.1 (the latest builds).

Comment: I tried the code (Windows 7 64-bit, 64-bit JVM, Scala 2.9.0.1), and get the exception

Comment: I cannot duplicate this on Windows 7 32-bit 32-bit JVM, scala 2.9.0.1.

Comment: @Ian I tried the following combinations and all fail: Scala 2.9.0.1 with WinXP, WinVista (both 32 bit), Windows 7 64 bit with 64 bit jvm. I have posted a file that can be run outside REPL. can you please try this.

Comment: I can confirm the issue using the updated code.  I guess I just needed to let it run a few more times.  I don't have a good solution for you, though.

Comment: @Ian The solution right now is to use an older version of Scala. 2.8.x works fine.

Comment: @Jus12 -- "Doctor, Doctor, it hurts when it do *this*!" "Well, stop doing that!"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does appear to have been a bug in the Actor framework. Looks like you're never supposed to get a RuntimeException. [See the Scala Bug Tracker](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4759) for details. It was fixed July 7th 2011, and is probably awaiting release.